# How do I access the position of a node's label?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

This is an extract of my code:

```
\node (secondsong) [matrix,draw, rounded rectangle,label={song}]{
    \node (fstittel) {\_tittel};
    \node (fstittelvar) [right=of fstittel, rectangle, draw] {``Money''};
    \node (fsartist) [below=2pt of fstittel] {\_artist};
    \node (fsartistvar) [right=of fsartist, rectangle, draw] {``Pink Floyd''};\\
};
```

I now want to make a rectangle around the label of my node, and make an arrow into the `secondsong` box. **How do I do this?**

I tried `\path[draw, -latex'] (secondsong.label) -> (secondsong);` to draw the arrow, but there is no such thing as a `.label` variable for a node.

Is this possible out of the box, or do I need to make my own custom node, positioned above my box?

[image: screen of the current]
[image: screen of the desired]

Comment: You should provide an MWE (complete but small document) which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I added a couple of screenshots. Nevertheless, the question is quite simple: How can I access the position of the label of a node?

Comment: well, meantime one "good soul" offer you service "I will do this instead of you" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! You can give the label a name and a style.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (secondsong) [matrix,draw, rounded rectangle,
label={[name=song, rounded rectangle,draw,yshift=1em]:song}]{
    \node (fstittel) {\_tittel}; 
    \node (fstittelvar) [right=of fstittel, rectangle, draw] {``Money''}; 
    \node (fsartist) [below=2pt of fstittel] {\_artist}; 
    \node (fsartistvar) [right=of fsartist, rectangle, draw] {``Pink Floyd''};\\
};
\path[draw, -latex'] (song) -- (secondsong);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me mention that you could also use a `pin`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin edge/.style={latex'-}]
\node (secondsong) [matrix,draw, rounded rectangle,
pin={[rounded rectangle,draw]above:song}]{
    \node (fstittel) {\_tittel}; 
    \node (fstittelvar) [right=of fstittel, rectangle, draw] {``Money''}; 
    \node (fsartist) [below=2pt of fstittel] {\_artist}; 
    \node (fsartistvar) [right=of fsartist, rectangle, draw] {``Pink Floyd''};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you want all the pins (in a scope, say), have a rounded rectangle border, use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin edge/.style={latex'-},every pin/.style={rounded rectangle,draw}]
\node (secondsong) [matrix,draw, rounded rectangle,
pin={above:song}]{
    \node (fstittel) {\_tittel}; 
    \node (fstittelvar) [right=of fstittel, rectangle, draw] {``Money''}; 
    \node (fsartist) [below=2pt of fstittel] {\_artist}; 
    \node (fsartistvar) [right=of fsartist, rectangle, draw] {``Pink Floyd''};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, obviosuly. That makes sense. I didn't know you could nest information inside the label.

Comment: @mazunki Since Schrödinger's cat has help you, you should say thank you by _accepting_ the answer and upvote it.

Comment: I was waiting for the 5 minute cooldown. The answer is perfect.